# Closing a file after writing recursively

Tags: java, file, recursion

I don't know why my code only writes in the file the first time and then nothing, I think the problem is salida.close() but i'm not sure. A bit of help will be appreciated. The method itself saves a binary tree in a file. If you need more information, ask me. Here is my code:

```
public boolean guardarAgenda() throws IOException
{
    NodoAgenda raiz;
    raiz = this.root;
    guardar(raiz);
    if(this.numNodes == 0)
        return true;
    else return false;

}
public void guardar(NodoAgenda nodo) throws IOException 
{
    FileWriter fich_s = new FileWriter("archivo.txt");
    BufferedWriter be = new BufferedWriter(fich_s);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(be);
    Parser p = new Parser();
    if (nodo != null)
    {
        guardar(nodo.left);
        p.ponerPersona(nodo.info);
        String linea = p.obtainLine();
        salida.println(linea);
        guardar(nodo.right);
        this.numNodes--;
    }

        output.close();

}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to write the code in English. It's difficult to help you without knowing what the method names mean.

Comment: I´ll change it to english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the same file on multiple calls without even the option of [appending content](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29). So no wonder you are not finding what you expect in it once processing ended.

When working with recursion and using the same resource on each call it's better to have a second method that takes that result as argument, and does only the writing/adding to it, opening/instantiation should happen in a method which initiates the first call, something similar to this:

```
public void guardar(NodoAgenda nodo) throws IOException 
{
    FileWriter fich_s = new FileWriter("archivo.txt");
    BufferedWriter be = new BufferedWriter(fich_s);
    PrintWriter salida = new PrintWriter(be);
    if (nodo != null)
    {
        guardar(nodo.left, salida);
    }
    output.close();
}


public void guardar(NodoAgenda nodo, PrintWriter salida) throws IOException 
{
    if (nodo != null)
    {
        Parser p = new Parser();
        guardar(nodo.left);
        p.ponerPersona(nodo.info);
        String linea = p.obtainLine();
        salida.println(linea);
        guardar(nodo.right, salida);
        this.numNodes--;
    }
}
```